# What's the easiest way to run a .js javascript file on windows?

Tags: javascript

When you try and run (not edit) a Javascript file, It will give an error that sounds like it is missing a reference in your code.  For Example, I got:

```
Line: 3 Char: 1

Error: 'document' is undefined'

Code: 800A1391

Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

Is it trying to execute a program similar to VBScript?  Should I be running it with another program?

Comment: JScript is a script run time engine which has a similar syntax to JavaScript (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript for the longer story about lawsuits) and is the default handeler for `.js` files.  `document` is a global object available inside browsers' JavaScript engine (which JScript does not define). As for how to "run" it, you probably need to create an `html` file that references the script and double click on that

Comment: A script is expecting an environment to use for something. What is your script supposed to do? Apparently it expects a DOM. One cannot just "run a file" and expect everything to fall in place.

Comment: if you want a more modern engine, you can associate node.js with .js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works a lot like VBScript.  I suggest visiting w3schools.com if you want to learn javascript.  Also check out this similar question https://superuser.com/questions/276614/running-javascript-files-js

Comment: This is a comment rather then an answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Windows Script Host (WSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Version_history) is a Microsoft technology used to run script files in various languages: it connects a script file with a script engine to run it. It has been around since Windows 95 and it's documentation can be found on the web.

If you double click on a `.js` file, and if WSH has not been disabled, it results in Microsoft's "JScript" script engine being run to execute the script with JavaScript bindings for the execution environment which include access to the file system and shell. It does not provide a browser environment or HTML rendering, so `document` flags as undefined.

To run a browser script, run it in a browser. Systems scripts *might* be written to run under WSH but there is a newer "PowerShell" replacement under Windows. [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) provide alternative cross platform capabilities and features.

Note that the name "JScript" originated during browser wars of the last century. Let's not go there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to "run a JS File" is to create an HTML file that references the JS file and let the default browser run it.  An example of a simple HTML file that would do this (assuming the script was named `script.js` and in the same folder as the html file (named `script.html`):

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>My Script</title>
   <script src='script.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

As a side note, on windows you could name your `html` file `script.hta` and it will open in Internet Explorer and in a window without an address bar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application), depending on your environment this might be a tad easier.